# Kronecker delta in multivariate Taylor expansion

Tags: summation, index-notation, kronecker-delta

I find the following equation in a quantum theory book where multivariate Taylor expansion was discussed. The equation uses Kronecker delta to change the subscripts which looks bizarre to me, and it goes

$$\phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu}\right)\left.u_{i \kappa, \alpha} u_{i \kappa, \beta}\right.=\left[\sum_{j^{\prime} \nu^{\prime}} \phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{i}+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}-\boldsymbol{R}_{j^{\prime}}-\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu^{\prime}}\right)\right] \delta_{i j} \delta_{\kappa \nu}u_{i \kappa, \alpha} u_{j \nu, \beta},\tag{1}$$

where $\phi$ is a function of the difference of two coordinates, $\boldsymbol{R}_i+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}$ and $\boldsymbol{R}_j+\boldsymbol{d}_{\nu}$. And $\phi_{\alpha\beta}$ is
$$\phi_{\alpha \beta}\left(\boldsymbol{R_{i}+d_{\kappa}-R_{j}-d_{\nu}}\right)=\frac{\partial^{2} \phi\left(\boldsymbol{R_{i}+d_{\kappa}-R_{j}-d_{\nu}}\right)}{\partial R_{i \alpha} \partial R_{i \beta}}.\tag{2}$$

with $R_{i\alpha}$ being the $\alpha$-element of coordinate $\boldsymbol{R}_i$. If $u_{i\kappa,\alpha}$ is the displacement of the coordinate $\boldsymbol{R}_i+\boldsymbol{d}_{\kappa}$ at $\alpha-$direction, then **where does the summation in (1) come from?** I'm trying to derive (1) using the properties of Kronecker delta but so far not much progress has been made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RHS of eq.(1) should be first written as:

$$\sum_{j^{\prime}\nu^{\prime}}\phi_{\alpha\beta}(\boldsymbol{R_i+d_{\kappa}-R_{j^{\prime}}-d_{\nu^{\prime}}})\delta_{jj^{\prime}}\delta_{\nu\nu^{\prime}}u_{i\kappa,\alpha}u_{i\kappa,\beta}$$

and then

$$\sum_{j^{\prime}\nu^{\prime}}\phi_{\alpha\beta}(\boldsymbol{R_i+d_{\kappa}-R_{j^{\prime}}-d_{\nu^{\prime}}})\sum_{j\nu}\delta_{jj^{\prime}}\delta_{\nu\nu^{\prime}}u_{i\kappa,\alpha}\delta_{ji}\delta_{\nu\kappa}u_{j\nu,\beta}$$

which gives

$$\sum_{j^{\prime}\nu^{\prime}}\phi_{\alpha\beta}(\boldsymbol{R_i+d_{\kappa}-R_{j^{\prime}}-d_{\nu^{\prime}}})\delta_{ij^{\prime}}\delta_{\kappa\nu^{\prime}}u_{i\kappa,\alpha}u_{j\nu,\beta}$$